# Are "condition" and "situation" interchangeable in the context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

1) He has been in a coma for three months. His condition/situation is still very complicated, but we're not ready to give up on him yet.

2) He has been in a coma for three months. His condition/situation remains unchanged, but we're not ready to give up on him yet.

Are "condition" and "situation" interchangeable and equally natural in the contexts above?

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as the definition/explanation and examples in a dictionary or other trusted reference.

Comment: _Condition_ is usually used when speaking of a sick person. A person's _situation_ could refer to anything (employment, marital status etc.)